# How to calculate miles of road in street network

Tags: network-analyst, network, road, streets

I have a road network we use for our city. It has ever single road created and categorized.

What would I do if I wanted to calculate the total miles of roads in this network?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this task. One of the more straight forward ways is to dissolve your feature class, using the road name as your dissolve field. Each road will now be a single feature, and you can check its length.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your length field -> statistics -> look at the SUM field